# How to abort a upload in tcp?

Tags: c#, tcp, upload, taskmanager, cancellation

I actually write a tcp client/server application. The client is able to upload some files to the server. The file will be splitted in several smaller packets. There is a streamreader which reads a file in blocks, this blocks will be send to the server while the file is reading to end. So, if the client will upload a large file, he should have a option to abort this upload. How I can do this?
My idea is quite simple: The upload is on the client and also on the server in a seperate task/thread. A simple class managed all these task like a task manager, in this, I can cancel any tasks. If the client say: "abort", the client will send a packet with this command and a task id. At the same time, the client stop to send other packets from this file. The server retrieve the command "abort" and will cancel the task in the task manager. Not only the client can cancel a upload/download, also the server can do this. Is this the correct way to handle this?

Comment: @Adil That's not what `EndSendFile` does. Also it seems OP isn't using `BeginSendFile` method.

Comment: Sending some keyword to server which server can understand the cancellation of the file seems like a good idea for me. Before implementing this yourself, I'd suggest you to check if anyone already done this (which is the case usually).

Comment: Just close the TCP connection. each end is notified that the other end is not going to send anything anymore. Doing a close on one end of the socket is called a halfclose. Note that TCP also has an abort method, but I don't think you need it here.

Comment: This isn't an option. Of course the client will send some other packets to the server. A reconnect is bad, the client have to login into the server.

Comment: The question is too broad. Based on requirements stated so far, you will need to have some kind of negotiation in the protocol for the client to identify what's valid data and what's not (i.e. where the server terminates sending data). This will preclude the use of a simple `StreamReader` to read the data, unless you use a separate socket for a "control" connection. In any case, without you making some attempt to solve the problem yourself, so that you can ask a _specific_ question, it's off-topic on SO.